# Basis of a polynomial ring over the field of Rationals

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

I need help checking the validity of the method of my proof and completing it.

> We observe the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x] $ as a vector space over
> the field $\mathbb{Q}$ it is easy to see from the definition that the
> monomial $ (x^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N_0}}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x] $
> show that the polynomial $((x-1)^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N_0} } $ is also a basis.

I had a tough time proving this statement. Firstly I know that a set $B$ in a vector space $V$ forms a basis of that vector space if it is linearly independent and $B$ spans the vector space but I couldn't manage to show that these are true for this case.

I started by using the Binomial Theorem to establish that polynomial is a linear combination: $$(x-1)^n =\sum_{n=k}^{k} \binom{n} k (-1)^n(x)^{n-k} = x^n-nx^{(n-1)}+ \binom{n}{2}(x)^{(n-2)}-\binom{n}{3}(x)^{(n-3)}+...+(-1)^{n}$$
To show that this linear combination is linearly independent, all of its scalar multipliers need to be equal to zero. If I'm not mistaken: $$\sum_{n=k}^{k} \binom{n} k (-1)^n(x)^{n-k} = 0 \implies  \binom{n} 0=\binom{n} k=\binom{n} 2=...=\binom{n} n=0$$
Does this not result in a logical contradiction? I thought that $\binom {n}k $ could never be equal to $ 0$? How do I show that the polynomial also spans $\mathbb{Q}[x] $?

Comment: You can use the binomial formula in the form $x^n=((x-1)+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n} k (-1)^n(x-1)^{n-k}$. This shows that $(x-1)^n, n=1,2 ,...$ span the vector space. If these were linearly dependent, that is $\sum \alpha_n(x-1)^n=0$ then substitute $y=x-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n\in\Bbb N$,$$x^n=\bigl((x-1)+1\bigr)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(x-1)^k,$$and therefore $x^n$ is a linear combination of polynomials of the form $(x-1)^k$. So, since the $x^n$'s span $\Bbb Q[x]$, then $(x-1)^n$'s also span it.

Now, let us see that $\{1,x-1,(x-1)^2,\ldots,(x-1)^n\}$ is linearly dependent. Let $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be scalars such that$$a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)^2+\cdots+a_n(x-1)^n=0.$$If you expand the LHS of the previous equality, you get a polynomial of degree $n$ such that the coefficient of $x^n$ is $a_n$. But the $x^n$'s are linearly independent, and therefore $a_n=0$. So, you know that$$a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}(x-1)^{n-1}=0,$$and you can start all over again, showing that $a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}=\cdots=a_1=a_0=0$.